# Finding the eigenvector of a sparse stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to ask whether there exists an analytical, or fast numerical, solution for finding the eigenvector, $\bf\pi$, associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ of the Algebraic equation:

$${\bf \pi} = {\bf \pi Q}_L$$

where '${\bf Q}_L$' is a stochastic matrix with size $2^L \times 2^L$ and a structure (shown here is an example for the case of $L = 3$):

$${\bf Q}_3=\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 & {\bar p}_1 &0 & 0& 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & p_2 & {\bar p}_2 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &0 & 0& p_3 & {\bar p}_3 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &0 & 0& 0 & 0 &p_4 & {\bar p}_4\\
p_5 & {\bar p}_5 &0 & 0& 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & p_6 & {\bar p}_6 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &0 & 0& p_7 & {\bar p}_7 &0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &0 & 0& 0 & 0 &p_8 & {\bar p}_8\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where ${\bar p}_i= 1 - p_i$.

This question is here because of the computer memory problem that appears when trying to solve it for large L's, and so the look for an analytical solution (does one do exist for such matrices?), or alternatively a fast numerical approach.
Many thanks in advance for any comment and/or advice!